# Solar electric home

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, solar, inverter

I want to see if my house can go completely solar. It's a small house with 240v 100A of electricity so about 24kW. I'm still new to this whole solar panel subject, this is my first time utilizing it in a big appliance so I need some verification IF the wire-ups it'll work.

I want to see if I need to get a 24v 300 watt solar panel, I did some calculations which means I need to get 80 pieces of the same solar panel.

Then I need an inverter. I found 3kW inverter 24vDC to 120/240VAC so I think I need to get about 8 of them. 10 solar panels will merge and wire up to an inverter input. All inverters output merges inside the Solar power box (Most likely won't work) OR just one 24kW inverter, and the solar power box should generate 240vAC 100A and hooks up to the main breaker.

I'm still developing a battery backup plan for the night so this won't be included in this topic. Any heaters WON'T be a part of electric appliances. But, I do need some more backup power (at least 40A) for other appliances like power tools after all the main appliances like refrigerator, laundry, and lights just in case I'll be using 90A out of 100A.

PS: I do not have any electric utility-provided power nowhere near my house.

Overall, my main question is, would I be able to generate 240vAC 100A of electricity by utilizing products above I mentioned during the daytime?

Will the products and the wire up process above be able to achieve my goal OR is there any better way for me to achieve it like if I need a different product or wire up differently?

Comment: You don't actually USE 24kW at once most of the time, **if ever.** I strongly suggest that you go do some reading and educate yourself just a wee tiny bit...there are plenty of resources out there that will do that a lot faster than asking questions here will. Start by looking at your electric bills for the past year or two to see how many kWh's you actually used.

Comment: You're off to a good start, but it's time to slow down and do more research.  I realize you're focusing on the products you are finding easily, but there are many more products out there, sizing is more complicated than that, and stuff doesn't work as you are assuming (e.g. you can't merge the output of 8 inverters, nor would you want to consider that before looking at the battery).

Comment: – Harper - Reinstate Monica I see, then I guess if I find another way to get all solar panels on line and find a 24kW inverter. Since I do know that DC can be merged by either more voltage or more current. But with AC, it'll be different. It's my first time to find a way to combine AC power FYI.

Comment: Just because someone recommends that you do _more_ learning than you have already done doesn't make that person a "bully". You have 2 very highly rated users who have answered 100s of electrical questions (including those about solar) asking you for details and making suggestions. Calling them names isn't earning you any points and only lowers other's opinion of you.

Comment: – FreeMan I see, but I have also added that I don't have any utility-provided electricity nowhere near me. And he told me about measuring kW, IK what he's talking about, just the thing is that this is a small house without any electric utilities so I can't really Measure it.

Comment: The fact that you don't have current electric service at the house doesn't mean he's a "bully" for suggesting that you measure current usage, it means he didn't know that until you told us. BTW, @JasonStones, you "ping" a user with the `@` then the first character or 2 of their user name, then click on the one you want. Then the person gets notified that you're talking to him.

Comment: @FreeMan I have, I do apologize for what I said, but also, I don't see a need to measure since; A, I need a backup power (Amps left after all main appliances). B, Incase I need more, I'll just replace it with 120A breaker. I've heard that off-grid would be a good use, but I'll still look for more since this is actually my first time working on inverters and I see there are different type. It just in my time, I need to be more quick on finding the best way for an achievement. 80 panels is the first part done, then I just need to find a way to get 240vAC and 100A out of it. Lets start here.

Comment: Don't just assume 80 panels is all you need.  You still need to get a racking system to mount them.  With 80 you're almost certainly going to need a ground-mount system.  72 cell panels (which is what you have @ 300W) are 0.992m wide.  So a 2-row system (common) will be at least 40-45m wide.

Comment: So "you have no utility-provided-power anywhere near" - presumably you are running a generator if you have power now, though you don't say - so, how much fuel, of what type does that eat in a year, or a month? If you don't have a kWh meter on it, consider spending not much money to have that basic information available to you, as you'll likely need to resort to generator power at least some of the time unless you have a VERY large budget and a well designed solar system + favorable weather.

Comment: Can you provide us with *MUCH* more information about the *actual loads involved* here? Do you have propane or gas service, or are all your big loads (space heating, hot water, clothes drying, cooking) electric?  What size generator do you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have utility-provided electric service now, then you probably want to use a GRID-TIED inverter and generally fewer are better than more unless you go the "micro-inverter" route. For example I have a system with 50 330W panels and one Fronius Primo 15KW inverter. It's sized to provide 100% of my average usage but there are scenarios that exist where it cannot provide the peak power needed. At those times the extra power needed is drawn from the grid.

I don't use any battery storage because where I live the utility must offer NET METERING which means they pay me the same rate that they charge me. So the power company effectively acts like a giant battery. In places where there are different rates for buying vs. selling power, then a battery system MAY make sense but you need to do the calculations to determine that based on your situation.

Multiple grid-tied inverters can be tied together on the AC side since they are designed to feed a "live" power grid.

So assuming you really need 80 panels that would easily be split into two 40 panel arrays of 12KW each and you could use two 12KW grid-tied inverters to generate your power.  I am not aware of any 24KW inverters currently on the market.

So as a point of reference for you, my system was switched on in October 2018.  I have not paid for any net usage of electricity since December 2018.  Since then there has been an increase in "reserve" to about 7000 KWH today.

If you have your past electric bills, you should be able to figure out your average annual usage and there are plenty of online calculators or local installers who can help you properly size the system.

Comment: I'll look into it, I think a grid-tied inverter is just what I need, just FYI I don't actually have any utility provided electric power source anywhere near my house so. I just updated my post with it and its on a "PS" note.

Comment: In that case you do not want grid-tied.  They will ONLY work when there is grid-power.  They are designed to immediately shut down when the power goes out as a safety feature.

Comment: If you are off-grid, you want an OFF GRID inverter.  They are similar but don't require grid power and CANNOT be connected to the grid.  You may want to combine one off-grid and one grid-tied inverter if you need to but check with your specific supplier to see if that use is supported.

Comment: If you are wanting battery backup, you can buy a pre-packged unit like a Tesla Powerwall or similar or you can roll your own using batteries, a charge controller, and an inverter that takes battery power as input.

Comment: Then I'll go ahead and find out about the off-grid and see which one I need, and thanks for mentioning me about the battery.

Comment: @jwh20 your utility are cheap then, we got a 25 year contract for 1 kwh exported at $1 while 1 kwh imported was $0.20, but they don't do those any more... Sadly we are just over halfway through...

Comment: I'm in Indiana and while they did change the law on net metering in the power company's favor but it's phased out over a number of years.  I'm grandfathered into net metering for 15 years then it starts to phase out.  Yes, it's a good deal!!